# Shell scripting: cat configuration archive

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Right now in the bash script I have this:

```
firstParam=$1
secondPara=$2
if [ -n $firstParam ] ; then 
    if [ $firstParam != "--x" ] ; then
        echo "Incorrect"
    else
       if [ -n $secondParam ]; then
           cat $secondParam
       else
           echo "Need file"
       fi    
   fi
fi
```

This script should open a configuration file and display only the lines that are not commented (#, ; or /) . Also the first parameter is not obligatory.
Can you help me, please? I have no idea how can I say that the first parameter is not necessary and if you don't put him it also can do the CAT. What I mean is that you can execute the script with "name.sh file.conf" or "name.sh --x file.conf"

PS: First parameter would be a function that, if you run the script with "--x file.conf" will do a "cat -n".

Comment: No, you should only ever consider the first parameter: `case` on it, process that then `shift` away the parameter (plus any arguments to it you have read too) and then loop back to the start of the case to process the next parameter.

Comment: Right, that allows you to process an unlimited number of arguments, rather than just the first 9. Looping over a case also allows you to handle arguments in any order, and to handle multiple spellings of the same parameter easily.

Comment: You can access an arbitrary (up to implementation limits) number of positional paramters like `${105}`, but agreed, looping and shifting is the proper way to handle the positional arguments.

Comment: Right, that limit's only in DOS, isn't it? =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the way I usually handle arguments. I think it'd be a good base for you to use:

```
XPARAM=false
OPARAM="default value"
FILENAME="/dev/stdin"

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
        -x|--x-long-form)
            XPARAM=true
            ;;
        -o|--option-with-arg)
            shift
            OPARAM="$1"
            ;;
        -h|--help)
            echo "usage: $0 [-x] [-o arg] FILENAME"
            exit #Don't need to do more when the user admits confusion ;-)
            ;;
        *)
            if [ "$1" == "" ]; then
                echo >&2 "I hate you"
                exit 1
            fi
            FILENAME="$1"
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

if $XPARAM; then
    # Handle -x
fi

cat "$FILENAME"
```

This separates the processing of options from both the logic of what they do, and how they are interpreted, e.g. whether any are required or mutually exclusive. It's also nice becasue the `while ... case ... shift` stuff can be copy-pasted to a new program which handles its args totally differently—only the case branches need to be changed.

Comment: It would be better to use the GNU `getopt` program or the built-in `getopts` facility than ad-hoc systems such as you show.

Comment: I've always hated `getopts`. I don't like its syntax. This is much clearer to read, IMO.

Comment: I concur; I find that a `getopts` implementation tends to have the same length, complexity, and bug ratio as a "handmade" while/case, plus `getopts` has some quirks with corner cases which are easy to avoid with a custom parser. Nevertheless, perhaps a `getops` answer could be posted by someone who actually likes it?

Comment: Don't test if `$*` has non-zero length; it fails to recognize zero-length arguments properly (`./script.sh "" ""`). Instead, use `[ $# -gt 0 ]` (for strict POSIX compliance) or `(( $# > 0 ))`.

Comment: Oh, God! Zero length arguments? I think those should be outlawed outright! Updated to subvert them.